# Get dimensions - or proportions - of an SVG file with CairoSVG

Tags: python, svg, cairo

I'm using CairoSVG successfully in my Python project - [md2pptx](https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx).

It converts SVG to PNG and that is then scaled to fit a space on the relevant PowerPoint slide.

It would be better to scale the SVG file **on conversion** rather than subsequently. But I don't kno3w the proportions (or dimensions) of the SVG file.

Yes, I could parse the XML in my own code - but it's better not to.

CairoSVG appears to have an **internal** method for getting this information - but not an externalised one.

How can I use CairoSVG in Python 3 to get the proportions or dimensions?